# Save listbox items in database after ordering

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have an asp.net page with two listboxes and a save button. The user needs to transfer items from listbox1 to listbox2 according to his order I mean that user can choose witch item come in the first place and which come next.

After that my system suggest the results (most commonly) that achieve the ordered items, I hope you understand

I did the transfer method between the two listboxes and it work good. But I'm stuck in the save method, it can save the items after being in listbox2 but not in the same order of transferring (user order).

Here is my code for save button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
    string str;

    OracleCommand com;
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(strConnString);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            str = "insert into Criteria values('" + ListBox2.Items[i].ToString() + "')";
            com = new OracleCommand(str, con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        LabOut.Visible = true;
        LabOut.Text = "Upload succesful!";
        con.Close();
        //Response.Write("Inserted");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        LabOut.Visible = true;
        LabOut.Text = "Upload failed!";
    }
    finally
    {
       con.Close();
       con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It may seem like a small thing, but pay attention to spelling (especially in the title of your question) and to proper capitalization. You don't have a single upper-case letter in your question text. Attention to detail is an important asset for a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that database tables do not inherently have a concept of order.  Retrieving rows from a table never guarantees an order unless you use a `order by` clause.

You should add an additional column to your table (named, for example, "Sequence" or "Order").  It can be an int or some other sortable value.  You would then need to modify your insert statement:

```
str = "insert into Criteria(ItemValue, Sequence) values('" + ListBox2.Items[i].ToString() + "'," + i.ToString() + ")";
```

and retrieve the list using

```
str = "Select ItemValue from Criteria order by Sequence"
```

Answer (score 0):

@fifo follow me

1. 1st add a column in your database say it is SeqNo.
2. Then save your data with that. I mean generate SeqNo. for each listbox2 item and save it.
3. When you will fetch data from database into lintbox2 then use sql/linq ORDER BY on SeqNo. column and display them on which Order that you were saved. Simple.. :)